# Why can't my script write new files?

Tags: bash, scripting

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in {1..10}; do
    echo $n
    dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=$(( RANDOM + 1024 )) > /testingscript/file${n}.txt
done
```

I would like it to create a file in the /testingscript directory with the name file'n'.txt, where n is the number of the file. Instead, I am getting this error:

```
1
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file1.txt: No such file or directory
2
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file2.txt: No such file or directory
3
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file3.txt: No such file or directory
4
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file4.txt: No such file or directory
5
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file5.txt: No such file or directory
6
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file6.txt: No such file or directory
7
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file7.txt: No such file or directory
8
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file8.txt: No such file or directory
9
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file9.txt: No such file or directory
10
./create.sh: line 5: /testingscript/file10.txt: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong causing my script to not write new files? I should add that this script worked perfectly as intended on my VM running Ubuntu 16.04. I am now attempting to run this on a physical computer running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Do you really have a directory `testingscript` in your root directory?

Comment: You specify the output file using the `of` option of `dd`, i.e. `of=/testingscript/file${n}.txt`

Comment: A little more context to @Inian 's comment. dd has an option to specify the output file that it is writing to. That option is called `of`. You can read more about that [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no directory

```
 /testingscript
```

If you want to create files in the current directories folder

```
yourCurrentDir/testingscript
```

You should remove the first "/" and use testingscript/file${n}.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {1..10}; do
        echo $n
        dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=$(( RANDOM + 1024 )) > testingscript/file${n}.txt
done
```

To check if there is a directory /testingscript

```
ls / | grep testingscript
```

The expected output is

```
testingscript
```

Comment: You could also have created the directory `/testingscript` with `mkdir`, but it's considered bad practice to frivolously make new directories directly under `/`. It's better to write it relative to the current dir (like this answer), your home dir, or `/tmp`

Comment: I do have a directory though. Here is the results of an ls:

~/Thesis/Scripts# ls
create.sh  testingscript

Comment: This "~/Thesis/Scripts# ls create.sh testingscript " seems like you are not in your root directory but in a directory "~/Thesis/Scripts". Try running "cd /" and then ls and check if you have a "testingscript" directory there. Also you can run pwd to see where you currently are.

Comment: That lists your current directory, which is exactly what this answer would use. The full path is something like `/home/youruser/Thesis/Scripts/testingscript`. Your posted script instead tried to write to `/testingscript` (i.e. next to `/home`, not next to your `create.sh`)